# How I can use HashMap with variables? Java sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two variables (nom and marc) that come from a database (sqlite). I need to show these variables with a HashMap. I tried the following but it does not work:

```
private void populateList(String nom, String marc) {
    list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, nom);
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, marc);
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "1");
    list.add(temp);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

In a click event of a button I use a cursor to fetch data from the database:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from prod where id_prod = " + id, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        String nom = c.getString(1);
        String marc = c.getString(2);

        populateList(nom, marc);
    } while(c.moveToNext());
}
```

As you can see PopulateList is a method different from the button that I need to send the variables. Maybe that I am doing wrong. Any answer will help. Thanks

Comment: "I try this but It does not work." "what am I doing wrong?" What are you trying to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you don't really want to be replacing `list` with an empty list every time you call `populateList` - otherwise you could just store the `HashMap` reference directly.

Comment: I need to populate a list , each item must appear after the button click event . So I need to show the variables "nom" and "marc" . I think I 'm sending wrong variables because nothing in the list is displayed . But neither error. It is as if the variables were null.  
I explain ?

Comment: Thanks andy... I solved ... it was so silly the solution!
I dissolved the method populateList and I References directly! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time that a the populateList() method is called, you create a new instance of the list that you want to render!
Try to remove

```
 list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

from the populateList(...)

Comment: Thanks daN... I solved ... it was so silly the solution!
I dissolved the method populateList and I References directly! thanks a lot!